# What is the future of valuable yet closed "Non Constructive" questions on SO? (Best of, hidden features, etc)

Tags: feature-request, questions

I want to ask and read responses from many "non constructive" questions.  I also understand that the format of this site does not lend itself well to those questions.

Since there is value in the questions and answers, and the audience is appropriate what is the plan / roadmap for these questions?

What format (other than Q&A) is best for those questions (e.g. hidden features of Android)?

Comment: To answer your title, the future of such questions (on this site) is [blight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114908/why-were-historically-significant-questions-deleted), even if there was a time they were popular.

Comment: We need to solve the more immediate problem of preservation: I would hate see the loss of the IDE/tool comparison rubrics. Why can't they make a sepedia or something?

Comment: @prusswan, I think you will always be able to harvest them from the data dumps the developers release from time to time, as these are probably here to stay.

Comment: So to be clear, are closed and deleted questions available on the StackAPI?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's for content I have visited/favourited in the past, I won't know about the good things that were deleted before I got to see them.

Answer (score 8):

I think we can feel free to take the content and make blog posts out of them.  Just be sure to follow the rules outlined in [Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Would linking to the blog post in a comment under the original question be a good idea (assuming it's closed but not deleted yet)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Probably not.

Comment: So there will only be a link from the blog post to the question (required for proper attribution IIRC), but not the other way around. Duly noted :)

Answer (score 0):

> So to be clear, are closed and deleted questions available on the StackAPI?

Some deleted content is visible to 10K+ users; I do not know if this data is available via the API or via database dumps, but it certainly remains in the database.

Some deleted content is destroyed completely, leaving no remnants to moderators, 10K+ users, nor developers. It will not be available via the API or database dumps. (See *Copyright Policy* in the [legal link](https://stackexchange.com/legal).)

Comment: It's not there yet, but deleted posts will eventually be made available through the API: http://stackapps.com/questions/1917/provide-a-way-to-retrieve-questions-and-answers-that-have-been-deleted

Comment: @Bill: Kevin's answer makes me think that it will be restricted to just authenticated users with >10K reputation; is that a fair assumption?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the case.